# Generating private keys

Tags: mnemonic-seed, viewkey, privatekey, spend-key

So I've been playing around with a Rust Monero library and I wrote this piece of code.

```
fn main() {
    let msg = "inwardly jester boss puzzled medicate iris terminal problems epoxy atrium newt dummy aided bovine navy flying dozen lunar hiker enlist sovereign tucks velvet wonders aided";
    let s = curve25519_dalek::scalar::Scalar::hash_from_bytes::<sha2::Sha512>(msg.as_bytes());
    let private_key = monero::util::key::PrivateKey::from_scalar(s);
    let public_key = monero::util::key::PublicKey::from_private_key(&private_key);
    let kp = monero::util::key::KeyPair{view: private_key, spend: private_key};
    let address = monero::Address::from_keypair(monero::Network::Stagenet, &kp);
   println!("wallet: {}, priv key: {}", address, private_key);
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong. Also how can one wallet have 2 private keys with 1 mnemonic. I don't understand that.

Answer (score 0):

> Also how can one wallet have 2 private keys with 1 mneomonic

Monero uses two key pairs, view and spend. So there is a private view key, a public view key, a private spend key and a public spend key. When restoring from a seed (which is a recovery key), the private view and spend keys are then derived from the recovery key.

> let kp = monero::util::key::KeyPair{view: private_key, spend: private_key};

Your code is incorrect as it is trying to set both view and spend the private keys to the same value. They should be different.